# Smoke and flame not showing up in render view mode and in render

Tags: rendering

I started making a volcano simulation recently and suddenly, today when i finished rendering my sample animation I noticed that the smoke and fire of the volcano are not present, i went into the file and rebaked the smoke and fire then I went into the render view mode and I didn't see any smoke or fire there either! I should note here that in object view I saw all of the smoke how it should be.
Pleas help me, this is for a school project and i have to hand it in soon.
Here is a link to the .blend file and an image of the final 
render:
render:https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3fmv6547mkluc8/0188.png?dl=0
.Blend:https://www.dropbox.com/s/9l9lemt8x23zx3h/Volcano2.blend?dl=0

Comment: seems ok. did you try to render it with GPU? volumes can be rendered with GPU but not smoke/fire sim.

Comment: I originally rendered it with GPU but now when i changed it back to CPU I can see the fire but not the smoke, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your smoke bake has to be starting inside the start/end frames. If the sim start frame is before the timeline start, the sim won't start at all.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the great answer but if i want to have the smoke start from a certain point in the timeline how do i do it?

Comment: Change the timeline start, bake, change again for render.

Comment: thanks you are very helpful, I only forgot to ask you one thing, how do i make the smoke emitter to stop emitting smoke at a cretin frame?

Comment: in physics tab, change the flow source (surface and/or volume) to 0. This can be keyframed. If you use a particle system, use the Emission [End] in Particles tab.